# Sequential search with a keyword

Tags: java, arrays, search, sequential

My assignment asks me to make a criminal record program that prompts the user to input a criminal name, crime, and year of conviction and it would store it in an array using another class (Database). The class looks like this:

```
class Database { 
   String name;
   String crime;
   int year;
}
```

I made a method in which to do this to input my information, but when I tested it to show the list, it only showed the last criminal I inputted. Why is it doing this?

```
//method to input criminal records
public static void inputData() throws IOException {
    arr = new Database[3];        
    Database temp = new Database();        

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Enter criminal first and last name: ");
        String name = br.readLine();
        temp.name = name;        

        System.out.print("Enter crime: ");
        String crime = br.readLine();
        temp.crime = crime;

        System.out.print("Enter the year of conviction: ");
        int year = Integer.valueOf(br.readLine()).intValue();
        temp.year = year;

        // Copy the name, crime, year to the global variables
        arr[i] = temp;
        System.out.println(arr[i].name + " was convicted in the year " + arr[i].year + " for " + arr[i].crime + ".");
    }
}
```

I also need to do a sequential search based on a keyword the user inputs (the type of crime), then display the criminals that did that type of crime. Here's the method for the search:

```
//method to search data
public static int searchData() throws IOException{
    System.out.print("Which crime would you like to select? (arson, theft, assault) ");
    String searchKey = br.readLine();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i].crime.equals(searchKey)){ 
            return i;  //found it!
        }
    }
    //key was not found
    return -1;
}
```

My teacher is horrible at explaining, so I did research about the sequential search, but I still can't figure out how can I get it to display the list of criminals that committed that crime.

Answer (score 4):

You are adding reference to same instance in your array. You should create new instance every time inside the loop:

```
// Database temp = new Database();   // Remove this

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Database temp = new Database();
```

also, instead of directly accessing the fields in `Database`:

```
temp.name = name;
```

you should use *setters*, and make your fields private:

```
temp.setName(name);
```

Comment: This worked amazingly! Would you be able to help me with the sequential search? That's my main issue.

Comment: @Sal. What issue are you having with that?

Comment: The user must be able to input a search key for one of the crimes (arson, assault, theft) and the criminals that did those crimes should be listed. But I have to use a sequential search to find them. What am I expected to do with the return value in order to list them?

Comment: @Sal. You need a `List<Database>`, and then every time you find a match, add it to the `List` and then at the end, return the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

In this exercise I suggest you to use an enumeration for the crimes, so you can add other crimes that the application will recognize from the input of the user as explained by the code.

```
public enum Crime {
    ARSON{
        public String toString(){
            return "arson";
        }
    },
    ASSAULT{
        public String toString(){
            return "assault";
        }
    },
    THEFT{
        public String toString(){
            return "theft";
        }
    };

    public static String types(){
        return ARSON + ", " + ASSAULT + ", " + THEFT;
    }
}
```

I would not use the name Database for a criminal because it is misleading. Criminal or Outlaw is more appropriate.

```
public class Outlaw {
    private String name;
    private Crime crime;
    private int year;

    public Outlaw(String name, Crime crime, int year){
        this.name=name;
        this.crime=crime;
        this.year=year;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Crime getCrime() {
        return crime;
    }
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return new String(name + " was convicted in the year " + year + " for " + crime + ".");
    }
}

public class InputData {
    private static Scanner scanner;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Outlaw> criminals = inputData();
        showCriminals(criminals);
        showCriminalsForCrime(criminals);
        scanner.close();
    }
    public static List<Outlaw> inputData(){
        List<Outlaw> criminals = new ArrayList<Outlaw>();
        int numCriminals;

        System.out.print("How many criminals are you going to enter? ");
        numCriminals = scanner.nextInt(); scanner.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < numCriminals; i++){
            criminals.add(inputOutlaw());
        }

        return criminals;
    }
    public static Outlaw inputOutlaw() {    
        System.out.print("Enter criminal first and last name: ");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        Crime crime = inputCrime();
        System.out.print("Enter the year of conviction: ");
        int year = scanner.nextInt(); scanner.nextLine();

        return new Outlaw(name, crime, year);
    }
    public static void showCriminalsForCrime(List<Outlaw> criminals){
        System.out.println("Search the criminals for their crime");
        Crime crime = inputCrime();
        List<Outlaw> criminalsForCrime = getCriminalsFor(crime,criminals);
        if(!criminals.isEmpty()){
            for(Outlaw criminal : criminalsForCrime){
                System.out.println(criminal.toString());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("There are not criminals for" + crime);
        }
    }
    public static Crime inputCrime(){
        Crime crime = null;

        while(crime == null){
            System.out.print("Which crime would you like to select? " + Crime.types() + ": ");
            try{
                crime = Crime.valueOf(scanner.nextLine().toUpperCase().trim());
            } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                System.out.println("The crime is not in the application!");
            }
        }

        return crime;
    }
    public static List<Outlaw> getCriminalsFor(Crime crime, List<Outlaw> criminals){
        List<Outlaw> criminalsForCrime = new ArrayList<Outlaw>();

        for(Outlaw criminal : criminals){
            if(criminal.getCrime().equals(crime)){
                criminalsForCrime.add(criminal);
            }
        }

        return criminalsForCrime;
    }
    public static void showCriminals(List<Outlaw> criminals){
        System.out.println("CRIMINALS: ");
        for(Outlaw criminal : criminals){
            System.out.println(criminal.toString());
        }
    }   
}
```

Tell your teacher to explain better :D